# Add photo in object and show it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need your help. I try to insert in an array with objects of a photo, to erase and then to deduce. I have no errors in the code, but instead of a photo it shows me a photo icon. All my photos are in a separate folder inside the src folder. Tell me if I'm doing it right or how do I insert a photo into the object and then erase it? Thank you very much

Pizza.js

```
export let pizza_description = [
{ id: 1,
title: 'title 1',
image: 'bavarska.jpg'},

{ id: 2,
title: 'title: 2',
image: 'salami.jpg'}
]
```

Pizza_page

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {pizza_description} from "../Food_description/Pizza/Pizza";

export let Pizza_page = () => {

let [pizza, different_pizza] = useState(pizza_description)

return (<div>
{pizza.map(el => <div key={el.id}>
<img key={el.id} src={el.image}/>
<h1>{el.title}</h1>
</div>)}
        </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the images or put them in the public directory then reference them like

```
return (<div>
 {pizza.map(el => <div key={el.id}>
    // assuming that el.image = image name + extension
    <img key={el.id} src={`/pizPhotos/${el.image}`}/>
    <h1>{el.title}</h1>
     </div>)
  }
   </div>)
 }
```

Comment: How do I import images? In the public directory account, the photos are in the pizPhotos folder, which is located in the src folder. So how do I import? Thanks)

Comment: move the pizPhotos to the public directory